# iOS SideBar Like in Facebook But No Navigation Controller Needed

Tags: ios

Anyone knows a library that can display a sidebar depending on the Object selected?

I have searched CocoaPods library but what I found are those with Navigation Controller.

My Main View should look like this at first:

[image]

Then after clicking the "Soups" button inside the scrollview:

[image]

Comment: @julie- search for sliding window in cocoacontrol

Comment: have you done googling....?

Comment: @VivekSehrawat, I will try the JASidePanels as suggested by AdamG. Thanks for the reply! :)

Answer (score 1):

Check out JASidePanels:

https://github.com/gotosleep/JASidePanels

You will have to reformat the structure of your project somewhat (the root view controller will have to be an instance of JASidePanels), but otherwise you will be able to manage your project the exact same way.

Comment: great! exactly the library I'm looking for! thanks thanks! :)

Comment: I just found out that there's a NavigationController also. :(

Comment: The style with JASidePanels is it pushes the whole center view to the left. As for what I need to do, I just need to slide the view on top of the center view.

Comment: You can set how far to the left the center panel goes if that is your concern.  It is one of the settings in the .h file.